# Python-Use of list of lists

Tags: python, list, class, matrix, computer-science

> Construct a class named `Matrix` that expresses the meaning of the matrix of numbers. The initialization function, `__init__`, should take as an argument a list of lists of  numbers and should store it in the variable matrix.

> Before defining the variable, the matrix dimension must be checked for validity (i.e. if all lists have the same length).

> `__init__` should also define two lists with names `columns`, `rows`. These lists will consist of objects of the `Vector` class and will be the columns and rows vectors respectively. Also, the `dim` variable should be defined which will be a pair (set) of numbers where the first will be as many as the number of rows in the table and the second as many as the number of columns.

How do we give as an argument a list of list?
And how do we use this list of lists to check if all lists have the length?
And a third question, how do we use the list of lists to get a tuple of all rows and a tuple of all columns?

My code so far is :

```
class Matrix:
    def __init__(self, matrix) :
        self.matrix = matrix
        self.columns 
        self.rows  
        self.dim = (len(self.rows) , len(self.columns))
```

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but it _seems_ like you are trying to get StackOverflow to do your homework

Comment: No, I just want some help so that I start writing the code. I don't want the exact solution.

Comment: There is a lot of work ahead, in fact, you need to also implement a `vector` class apparently. The next step for you though is prior to assigning the self.matrix a value you need to verify that each sub-list of the provided list of lists is the same size. This info combined with the number of sub-lists will also allow you to set self.dim

Comment: I'm not sure how we answer those questions without just writing most of the code for you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Write a list whose elements are also lists, e.g. `[[1, 2], [3, 4]]`.
2. Get the length of the first list in the list of lists. Then use a function like `all()` to test if the lengths of all the other nested lists have the same length.
3. To make the `rows` variable, use a list comprehension to convert each row of `self.matrix` into a `Vector` and collect them into a list. To make the `colums` variable, use nested loops. The outer loop iterates over the column numbers (from `0` to `len(self.matrix[0])`), the inner loop iterates over each row, collecting all the values in the column number into a `Vector`. Then these vectors are collected into a list that's assigned to `self.columns`.